# Jackson: Deserialize one value to two java fields

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

So I have one field in my JSON

```
{
"Number": "2737212281"}
```

And I want to deserialize this field to two java fields

```
@Column(name = "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY", length = 5)
@JsonProperty("TransactionCurrency")
@JsonAlias({"Number"})
private String TransactionCurrency;

@Column(name = "SD_DOCUMENT_REASON", length = 3, nullable = true)
@JsonProperty("SDDocumentReason")
@JsonProperty("Number")
private String SDDocumentReason;
```

to have the same value in both fields, for some reason the lib just takes the first field(TransactionCurrency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@JsonCreator` could be an option.

For example, for JSON that looks like: `{ "field" : "anything" }`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

class Foo {
    private final String field0;
    private final String field1;

    @JsonCreator
    public Foo(@JsonProperty("field") String value) {
        this.field0 = value;
        this.field1 = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would certainly help, but in my case, some clients have to use the SDDocumentReason as field others use the Number(for deserialization)

But your comment was very helpful so I checking it :)